# Bootable USB iso for Windows7

Tags: boot, usb, windows, iso, unetbootin

I've used different USB bootable programs like Unetbootin to put an iso image into my USB and went into the boot menu to change the boot device but I get the message "missing operating system" before it starts my current OS (Kubuntu) again.

According to this (http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/create-bootable-windows-7-usb-drive.html) article:
*Some users have reported that some recent Unetbootin versions no longer let you select an USB drive formatted to NTFS and by formatting it to FAT, the Windows 7 installation fails.*

What do I do? [Deadline for Windows 10 update is tonight!]

**EDIT:** I've already tried downloading WinUSB as well (one of the many programs I've tried) and I never got past downloading it because I get

```
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
```

in the terminal.

EDIT 2: I went into `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` because I was going to try to comment a CD-ROM source, but it already was:

```
# deb cdrom:[Kubuntu 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.1)]/ xenial mai$
```

so the source code is not the issue..

**The terminal tells me the problem is:**

```
W: The repository http://ppa.launchpad.net/colingille/freshlight/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
```

I'm still looking for a way to solve this.. :(
**This is not a duplicate because I cannot download winUSB.**

tried disabling the ppa from the source code and running the steps again

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install winusb
```

nothing new.
Posted another question.. https://askubuntu.com/questions/804582/cant-download-winusb

Comment: The problem with installing winusb is a completely different issue.

Comment: Yes, I posted it as a separate question (at bottom of question) but I'm still looking for an alternative

Comment: You did not post it as a separate question. Now your question is a mess.

Comment: It's literally linked at the bottom of the question

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/804582/cant-download-winusb

Comment: I gave those details because people told me it was a duplicate, but it's not because downloading winUSB isn't possible for my version of Ubuntu